# Solution of a simple differential equation, but now I forget it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$\frac{dp}{dr}+\frac{p}{r}$=0

what's p?

It was originally a simple equation......

I have learned this part of knowledge before, but now I forget it......thanks

Comment: Look up "scalar linear differential equation of order one"

Comment: Use integrating factor.

Comment: It’s a separable differential equation

Comment: $$\frac{dp}{dr}=-\frac{p}{r}\\\frac{dp}{p}=-\frac{dr}{r}\\\int \frac{dp}{p}=\int -\frac{dr}{r}\\\ln|p|=-\ln|r|+\ln c\\p\times r =const$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dp}{dr}r+p=0$$

Or more generally

$$\dfrac{dp}{dr}F(r)+G(p)=0$$

Is a linear first order homogeneous ODE.
As suggested in the comments can be solved by separation of variables or integrating factor.